# Wifi - Ceiling Box

Tags: electrical, ethernet

I have a situation where I need to install a WAP to the ceiling.  It is not really the attachment that is the problem, it is about finding a ceiling box that will allow me to have a power outlet and route Cat5/6 cabling into it.

If i was at work, we would just purchase a cinch kit to the ceiling cross supports and attach the cisco wap.

This product is close but is a little too complicated for my need.
[image]

Needs:

- Inset into the ceiling, allowing for mounting points for the WAP
- Has the ability to have a standard 2 outlet power box to be attached
- Cable holes for additional wiring (Cat5/6), with or without termination (I have the termination port)
- All cabling should be hidden from view; i.e. within the box or "behind" the WAP

Outside of the points above, everything is up for grabs.  The WAP does not have to be hidden.

Comment: Not having all this hassle is why POE is great for ceiling WAPs. One box, one LV cable, done.

Comment: @Ecnerwal unfortunately, I don't have the equipment for POE right now.  Need to find a box, either way.

Comment: Even if you find a box, it needs to have room for a DC power adapter right?  I doubt your AP is going to take a direct 120VAC connection.  POE is the right, easy way to do this, and it doesn't take any "equipment".  You get a POE power injector that goes on the Cat5/6 cable going to the AP and that's it - done.  They even have pairs of POE adapters that inject power on one side and strip it out on the other side to power devices that don't natively support POE.

Comment: @JPhi1618: unofficial "POE" that strips out voltage on the other end often (always?) doesn't support  gigabit Ethernet. If you want the best throughput, you have to get the expensive gear. you might consider a basement placement as well; easier and can be ugly, and still allows a central placement.

Comment: @dandavis, there are dumb injectors/splitters that use the dead pairs of wire on non-gig, but now the "smart" splitters are [pretty cheap](https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Gigabit-Ethernet-Splitter-TL-PoE10R/dp/B003CFATQK) and support full gigabit.

Comment: Do you plan to involve mains power (120VAC, 230VAC, etc.) in any way whatsoever?

Comment: @Harper No...strictly low-voltage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Behind-TV outlet]

[image: another behind-TV outlet]

Two of the many "behind the TV Outlet Boxes" which you could stuff into your ceiling to solve this. Since you fail to provide any details about the WAP, hard to tell if you need a different sized one, but they come in many sizes and configurations.

*A single POE injector and a POE WAP are a much cleaner solution (and might cost less, even if you have a non-POE WAP in hand.)*

Comment: If you need model, it is Linksys EA6500, but would like a generally neutral box so if I change the WAP I wont have to change the box.  Even if I go through to POE, it is at a location that could benefit from an outlet in the ceiling for perceptibly other purposes.

Comment: So basically I should be looking for AV vendor sites?  Have any feeder links to place me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is a link to a similar product: https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=8475

Comment: And if you have a non-POE WAP, you could use this [POE Splitter](https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Gigabit-Ethernet-Splitter-TL-PoE10R/dp/B003CFATQK) to get DC power to it (along with a POE injector).